# Use robolectric test in android studio not class found

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have a project in Android Studio with gradle, i want to do some test with robolectric, at the moment, and later do it for the UI with roboguice.

Now i do a other java module named test, include in settings.gradle, and create a build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    def androidModule = project(':Firext')
    compile androidModule

    testCompile androidModule.android.applicationVariants.toList().first().javaCompile.classpath
    testCompile androidModule.android.applicationVariants.toList().first().javaCompile.outputs.files
    testCompile files(androidModule.plugins.findPlugin("com.android.application").getBootClasspath())

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.2'
}
```

The main test class:

```
package com.firext.test;


import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;
import org.robolectric.AndroidManifest;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;
import org.robolectric.res.Fs;

public class RoboElectricGradleTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {
    private static final int MAX_SDK_SUPPORTED_BY_ROBOLECTRIC = 18;

    public RoboElectricGradleTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {
        String manifestProperty = "../Firext/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml";
        String resProperty = "../Firext/src/main/res";
        return new AndroidManifest(Fs.fileFromPath(manifestProperty), Fs.fileFromPath(resProperty)) {
            @Override
            public int getTargetSdkVersion() {
                return MAX_SDK_SUPPORTED_BY_ROBOLECTRIC;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and the test class

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class EnterActivityTest {

    private EnterActivity activity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(EnterActivity.class).create().get();
    }

    @Test
    public void checkActivityNotNull() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(activity);
    }
}
```

But when i run all test in module i get this erro:

```
Class not found: "com.firext.test.activities.EnterActivityTest"
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to find the answer?

Comment: No i didnt but finally i could set up a project with robolectric test, but i cant find the tutorial..sorry